# Use JSON data offline Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift3

I'm a beginner so please be gentle.
Ok so I successfully parse my JSON from the server and can access all of its contents but know I'm kind of stuck here:

```
//Functionn for fetching API data
func fetchRates(){

    //Set EndPoint URL
    let url = URL(string: endPoint)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        }

        do {

            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

            let dictonary = json as? [String: Any?]

            let ratesJson = dictonary?["rates"] as? [String: Double]

            print(ratesJson as Any)



        } catch let jsonError {

            print(jsonError)

        }

    }.resume()


}
```

Now I want to get my ratesJson Dictionary out of this function and actually use its contents to do some calculations, but after hours of trying and searching I still have no idea how.

I just want to:

- Get JSON data stored presistently (for offline use)
- Update the Data when the app launches and overwrite the old data

The possibilities I've come across so far are CoreData, which seems really confusing and complicated and Realm which I don't really know at all.

Help would be very much appreciated and sorry if this seems really stupid

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the JSON parsing, I would create a object class to store the data using Core Data.  There is a lot that goes into core data usage at first, but it is well worth the time investment to learn if you plan on continuing iOS development. [Core Data Tuts](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

I also do not know what you plan on doing with your app, or the purpose, and Core Data might be a little overkill according to your purpose, but you could always save the updated JSON each time, overwriting a file in the device's document's dir, then read the data back in and parse it again.

You can write the JSON data to a outputstream using:

```
JSONSerialization.writeJSONObject(_ obj: Any, to stream: OutputStream, options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = [], error: NSErrorPointer)
//Write JSON data into a stream. The stream should be opened and configured. 
//The return value is the number of bytes written to the stream, or 0 on error. 
//All other behavior of this method is the same as the dataWithJSONObject:options:error: method.
```

UPDATE: Ok I think I see your question now.  There are two ways that you can go about getting your data back to your view controller: 1. Delegate pattern 2.Closures.  I personally like using delegates over closures.

With delegates you will need to create a protocol:

```
protocol SessionDataTaskComplete {
    func dataDownloaded(parsedJson : [String : Double])
}
```

And inside of your URLSession class you will need a class variable to hold that protocol delegate:

```
var dataTaskCompleteDelegate : SessionDataTaskComplete?
```

Then you will need to have your view controller implement that protocol:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, SessionDataTaskComplete {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Also assign your viewController as your URLSession's SessionDataTaskComplete delegate
        myURLSession.dataTaskCompleteDelegate = self
    }

    func dataDownloaded(parsedJson : [String : Double]) {
        //Handle data as you wish here
    }
}
```

Now in your fetchRates() you can use that delegate to pass the data back to your viewController:

```
func fetchRates(){

//Set EndPoint URL
let url = URL(string: endPoint)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {

        print(error as Any)

    }

    do {

        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

        let dictonary = json as? [String: Any?]

        let ratesJson = dictonary?["rates"] as? [String: Double]

        //print(ratesJson as Any)
        if (dataTaskCompleteDelegate != nil) {
            dataTaskCompleteDelegate!.dataDownloaded(parsedJson: ratesJson)
        }



    } catch let jsonError {

        print(jsonError)

    }

}.resume()


}
```

If you are not comfortable with using the delegate pattern, that is something else I would suggest spending time learning, as it is used all over with the iOS SDK.  Try to think of them as an object assigning a duty/task to another object.

Comment: I've read up on delegates and I'm really having trouble understanding anything...and I've tried using your code above but I can't get it working it doesn't let me do inside ViewDid Load  `var dataTaskCompleteDelegate : SessionDataTaskComplete?` I assume this is because my fetchRates() is inside the ViewController class (outside the ViewDidLoad) or something but I'm really struggling to understand

Comment: Yea that is the reason, normally you would have a separate class to your session tasks and data model changes.  In your case, since it's all in your view controller, instead of calling: dataTaskCompleteDelegate!.dataDownloaded(parsedJson: ratesJson), and creating the protocol, simply call to another function and pass the data.  I highly recommend that you look into and learn MVC as well (Model-View-Controller) architecture.

Comment: Ok well I'm gonna hold off on this and take a look at MVC since i really have no idea what to do thx for the help